# How can i Remove "(Continued)" from 2nd page?

Tags: curve-class

I am writing a CV.
After writing a couple of headers and sub-headers it jumps to the next page obviously. But the 2nd page comes with "(continued)" top row in the centre and its annoying. How do I remove this?

[image]

My code:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\documentclass{curve} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\leftheader{a\\   b\\   c\\   d\\   } 
\rightheader{   }  
\title{a} 
\subtitle{b     \\ \vspace{1mm}\Large  c}      

\begin{document}  
\makeheaders[t] 
\maketitle  
\makerubric{rubric}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: There are several cv-related LaTeX document classes and packages out there. You've got to tell us *which* document class and packages you employ.

Comment: **rubic** is a text document that it calls and in it : \begin{rubric}{}
\subrubric{ZXC}…………..\end{rubric}

Comment: For anyone who wants to remove the entire repeating header, you can check out this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591184/131165

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, because we do not have your used file `rubric.tex`. It would be mutch better you would add that file without personal informations to your question too.  **So we have to guess what you are doing!**

In that class `curve` from ctan is an command `\@continuedname` defined. You can change it to be empty with the following code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\def\@continuedname{}
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

If that does not help then please complete your given code to be complete and compilable reflecting your situation!

My complete test code (package `filecontents`is only used here  to have both tex file concatenated into one MWE):

```
\begin{filecontents*}{myrubric.tex}
\begin{rubric}{Education}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\entry*[2009 -- 2013]%
    \textbf{title, university, Germany} in computer science.
    \par Thesis title: \emph{The Title of the Thesis.} More details at \url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/}
%
\end{rubric}
\end{filecontents*}

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e} 
\documentclass{curve} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[swedish]{babel} 
\usepackage[paperheight=29.7cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\leftheader{a\\ b\\ c\\ d\\ } 
\rightheader{ } 
\title{a} 
\subtitle{b \\ \vspace{1mm}\Large c} 

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\def\@continuedname{}
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document} 
\makeheaders[t] 
\maketitle 
\makerubric{myrubric} 
\end{document}
```

and the resulting pdf:

[image: resulting cv]

Comment: It worked thank you!

Comment: Do you know if we can completely disable this “continuation” function? Please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63194068/how-to-remove-rubric-title-repeated-on-several-pages-latex-curve

Comment: @2523fewqf23f Please ask a new question on this page and add an MWE to it!

Comment: Hi @Mensch, sorry for the confusion! I was not sure if I should make a new question as it was asked in the URL I put above. So I have re-asked the question with link to the source code of my Latex and an example output PDF https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/590708/how-to-disable-repeating-continuation-of-section-header-in-latex-curve-for-cv

Comment: My TeX document changes in some ways when using `\makeatletter` or `\makeatother`. Adding only `\def\@continuedname{}` was sufficient for me. Thank you.