# How to disable repeating continuation of section header in Latex Curve for CV

Tags: sectioning, templates, cv

I am using Curve for my CV and every time a section goes beyond one page, its header will be repeated on the next page. Could anyone please tell me how could I disable this "feature"? I refer to this [Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479998/how-can-i-remove-continued-from-2nd-page) and could make the word "continued" disappeared, but couldn't figure out how to make the entire repeating header gone. A sample PDF using the same curve package can be viewed [here](http://liantze.penguinattack.org/cv-llt.pdf). Thanks for your help <3

[image: Annoying repeating section header in Latex Curve CV]

main file:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 16 September, 2016
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}

\usepackage{settings}


% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  %% Warning: EB Garamond contains no bold!! Substituting for Junicode Bold, but *may not look nice nor consistent*!!
%   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5},BoldFont=Junicode Bold]{EB Garamond}
  %% Charis SIL's rather nice, actually.
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setmonofont{Inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf  %% Comment out if you prefer lining figures rather than old style figures
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name and first name (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly for now...
% \myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
\myname{d'Andrimont}{Raphaël}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Arif Yulianto, S.Kom.}

  \makefield{\faCircleO}{\url{Bandung, 2 July 1994}}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{arify@outlook.co.id}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@bangarify}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://www.devarify.org/}}
  \makefield{\faPhone}{\texttt{081222300542}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/arifyulianto/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{arifyulianto.png}
\photoscale{0.30}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment}
\makerubric{education}

\makerubric{organizational}
\makerubric{project}
\makerubric{achievment}


\makerubric{skills}
\makerubric{interest}
%\makerubric{misc}

%\makerubric{referee}
% \input{referee-full}

\end{document}
```

settings.sty:

```
\RequirePackage{silence} \WarningsOff[longtable] \WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex} \newif\ifxetexorluatex \ifxetex   \xetexorluatextrue \else   \ifluatex
    \xetexorluatextrue   \else
    \xetexorluatexfalse   \fi \fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx} \RequirePackage[hyphens]{url} \RequirePackage[main=british]{babel} \raggedright

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=2.25cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry} \RequirePackage{relsize} \RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor} \RequirePackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment} \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{88AC0B} \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't need biblatex; delete this line. % \RequirePackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=apa,sorting=ydnt,uniquename=init,maxnames=7,defernumbers=true]{biblatex} % list of styles here: https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Biblatex_bibliography_styles \RequirePackage[backend=biber,sorting=ydnt,uniquename=init,maxnames=7,defernumbers=true,indexing=true]{biblatex} \DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}

\RequirePackage{tikz} \newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{    \node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.35ex,minimum width=1.5em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}
    \newcounter{bibitem}

% bring back this line if want to show sub-number inside circle for bib items % \AtBeginBibliography{\setcounter{bibitem}{1}} % \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[2.5em][l]{\circled{\thebibitem}\stepcounter{bibitem}}}

% \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small} \setlength{\bibitemsep}{1.5ex} \setlength{\bibhang}{2.7em} \NewBibliographyString{retrieved} \NewBibliographyString{from} \DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{   from = {\textcolor{MarkerColour!80!black}{\faLink}},   retrieved = {} }

\headerscale{1} %\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt} \rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily} \setlength{\rubricspace}{2pt} %\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt} \setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-3pt} \setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt} \setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt} \def\@@rubrichead#1{%   \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\   \shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (\@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);   \node[font={\@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};   \end{tikzpicture}%   \vspace\rubricspace% }

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily} \subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1}
#2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r} \rubricalignment{l} \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25} \urlstyle{tt}

\newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def\@prefixmarker{#1}} \def\@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%   \hspace*{-1ex}   \color{MarkerColour!80!black}\@prefixmarker%   \hspace*{1ex}% }

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip\@@rubrichead{#1}}

\defbibheading{subbibliography}{\vskip\subrubricbeforespace{\@subrubricfont\hspace{3pt}#1}\par}

\defbibfilter{booksandchapters}{% ( type=book or type=incollection ) }

\newcommand{\myname}[2]{%    \def\@mylastname{#1}%    \def\@myfirstname{#2}% }

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%   \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}% }

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%   \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartfamily}{\@mylastname}}
               and
               test {\ifdefstrequal{\namepartgiven}{\@myfirstname}}}
    {\textbf{#1}}%
    {#1}% }

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Please add  the package `settings` in order to be make your MWE compilable.

Comment: Hi @SimonDispa I added the `settings.sty`. Sorry for the omission initially. The complete Tex Repo lives here: https://github.com/digi-lab/pylatex-resume/tree/master/latex-cv-templates/A%2520Customised%2520CurVe%2520CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go from this "feature"

[image: a]

To this "un-feature"

[image: B]

add the code between `******  Add from here  <<<<<<<<<<<<<`  and

`**********  TO HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<` to your preamble.

I used the `cv-lit.tex` from link you provided and replaced

`\makerubric{skills}` by `\makerubric{profex}`

The the final code is

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% This CV example/template is based on my own
% CV which I (lamely attempted) to clean up, so that
% it's less of an eyesore and easier for others to use.
%
% LianTze Lim (liantze@gmail.com)
% 16 September, 2016
%
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve}

% Uncomment to enable Chinese; needs XeLaTeX
% \usepackage{ctex}


%% ********************************  Add from here  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{rubric}[1]{%
    \def\raggedright{%
        \@rightskip\@flushglue\rightskip\@rightskip\leftskip\z@skip}%
    \def\raggedleft{%
        \rightskip\z@skip\leftskip\@flushglue\parfillskip\z@skip}%
    \gdef\@beforespace{0pt}%
    \gdef\@nextentry{}%
    \gdef\@previouskey{}%
    \global\let\old@newpage\newpage%
    \global\let\old@pagebreak\pagebreak%
    \global\let\old@nopagebreak\nopagebreak
    \begin{longtable}{@{}kl@{~}X@{}}
        \@rubrichead{#1}\\*[\rubricspace]
        \endfirsthead
        \noalign{\@rubricmark{#1}%
            \global\let\in@newpage\newpage%
            \global\let\in@pagebreak\pagebreak%
            \global\let\in@nopagebreak\nopagebreak%
            \gdef\newpage{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@newpage}
            \gdef\pagebreak{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@pagebreak}
            \gdef\nopagebreak{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@nopagebreak}}}{%
        \@nextentry
    \end{longtable}\par\vspace\rubricafterspace
    \global\let\newpage\old@newpage%
    \global\let\pagebreak\old@pagebreak%
    \global\let\nopagebreak\old@nopagebreak}
\makeatother
%%% *****************************************  TO HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  %% Warning: EB Garamond contains no bold!! Substituting for Junicode Bold, but *may not look nice nor consistent*!!
%   \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5},BoldFont=Junicode Bold]{EB Garamond}
  %% Charis SIL's rather nice, actually.
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setmonofont{inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf  %% Comment out if you prefer lining figures rather than old style figures
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}

%% Only needed if you want a Publication List
\addbibresource{own-bib.bib}

%% Specify your last name and first name (as given in the .bib) to automatically bold your own name in the publications list. One caveat: You need to write \bibnamedelima where there's a space in your name for this to work properly for now...
\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}
% \myname{d'Andrimont}{Raphaël}

% Change the page margins if you want
% \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

% Change the colours if you want
% \definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{00FFFF}
% \definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{0000CC}

% Change the item prefix marker if you want
% \prefixmarker{$\diamond$}

%% Photo is only shown if "fullonly" is included
\includecomment{fullonly}
% \excludecomment{fullonly}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo}
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment}
\makerubric{education}

% If you're not a researcher nor an academic, you probably don't have any publications; delete this line.
%% Sometimes when a section can't be nicely modelled with the \entry[]... mechanism; hack our own and use \input NOT \makerubric
\input{publications}

%\makerubric{skills}
\makerubric{profex}

\makerubric{referee}
% \input{referee-full}

\end{document}
```

where the file `profex.tex` is

```
%%%%  file profex.tex

\begin{rubric}{Profesional Experiences}
\subrubric{Awards and Achievements}
\entry*[2020] \textbf{Merit Award}, 25-day Standard Course SC450, Outward Bound School, Lumut, Malaysia.
%
\entry*[2018] \textbf{Department Prize for Outstanding Student Performance}, Department of Computer Science, University of Warwick, United Kingdom.

\subrubric{Certifications}
\entry*[2017--present] \textbf{\textsc{Triz} Level 1 Practitioner}. Awarded by MyTRIZ Innovation Association, Malaysia.
\entry*[2006] \textbf{Certified IT Professional for \textsc{fitpe}} (Fundamental IT Professional Examination).  Awarded by Ministry of Higher Education Malaysia.

\subrubric{Employment}
\entry*[2018--present] \textbf{Merit Award}, 25-day Standard Course SC450, Outward Bound School, Lumut, Malaysia.
%
\entry*[2017--2017] \textbf{Department Prize for Outstanding Student Performance}, Department of Computer Science, University of Warwick, United Kingdom.

\entry*[2017--2016] \textbf{\textsc{Triz} Level 1 Practitioner}. Awarded by MyTRIZ Innovation Association, Malaysia.

\entry*[2016--2014] \textbf{Certified IT Professional for \textsc{fitpe}} (Fundamental IT Professional Examination).  Awarded by Ministry of Higher Education Malaysia.
\end{rubric}
```

**UPDATE:** how to use this modified template.

(1) Download the package `curVe`  from CTAN  https://ctan.org/pkg/curve?lang=en and install it.

(2) The template is  in here:

https://github.com/digi-lab/pylatex-resume/tree/master/latex-cv-templates/A%2520Customised%2520CurVe%2520CV

(3)  To the original cv template it must be added to its preamble the code between  `Add from HERE<<<` to  `TO HERE <<<<<<<`. See the  simplified version.

Aside from that you need to write your own separate .tex files named  `employment.tex` `education.tex`. `profex.tex` etc, all in the same directory with the photo.jpg, and `settings.sty` like this:

(Each   `\makerubric{<filename>}` expects to find   `filename.tex` starting with `\begin{rubic}{<title>})` and ending with `\end{rubic}`)

[image: z]

This is a simplified version of the modified template.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,skipsamekey,11pt,british]{curve} 

%% ********************************  Add from HERE  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{rubric}[1]{%
    \def\raggedright{%
        \@rightskip\@flushglue\rightskip\@rightskip\leftskip\z@skip}%
    \def\raggedleft{%
        \rightskip\z@skip\leftskip\@flushglue\parfillskip\z@skip}%
    \gdef\@beforespace{0pt}%
    \gdef\@nextentry{}%
    \gdef\@previouskey{}%
    \global\let\old@newpage\newpage%
    \global\let\old@pagebreak\pagebreak%
    \global\let\old@nopagebreak\nopagebreak
    \begin{longtable}{@{}kl@{~}X@{}}
        \@rubrichead{#1}\\*[\rubricspace]
        \endfirsthead
        \noalign{\@rubricmark{#1}%
            \global\let\in@newpage\newpage%
            \global\let\in@pagebreak\pagebreak%
            \global\let\in@nopagebreak\nopagebreak%
            \gdef\newpage{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@newpage}
            \gdef\pagebreak{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@pagebreak}
            \gdef\nopagebreak{\@nextentry\noalign{\gdef\@nextentry{}}\in@nopagebreak}}}{%
        \@nextentry
    \end{longtable}\par\vspace\rubricafterspace
    \global\let\newpage\old@newpage%
    \global\let\pagebreak\old@pagebreak%
    \global\let\nopagebreak\old@nopagebreak}
\makeatother
%%% *****************************************  TO HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{settings}

% Change the fonts if you want
\ifxetexorluatex % If you're using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,LetterSpace=5}]{Charis SIL}
  \setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lato}
  \setmonofont{inconsolata}
\else % If you're using pdfLaTeX or latex
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}
  \usepackage{fbb}
  \usepackage[type1]{cabin}
  \usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}
  \useosf  %% Comment out if you prefer lining figures rather than old style figures
\fi
\usepackage{csquotes}   

\myname{Lim}{Lian\bibnamedelima Tze}

\includecomment{fullonly}   

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  

\leftheader{%
  {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily Lim Lian Tze, Ph.D.}

  \makefield{\faEnvelopeO}{\texttt{liantze@gmail.com}}
  \makefield{\faTwitter}{\texttt{@liantze}}

  \makefield{\faGlobe}{\url{http://liantze.penguinattack.org/}}

  \makefield{\faLinkedinSquare}
  {\url{http://www.linkedin.com/in/limliantze/}}
}

\rightheader{~}
\begin{fullonly}
\photo[r]{photo} %
\photoscale{0.13}
\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}
\makeheaders[c]

\makerubric{employment} % uses file employment.tex
\makerubric{education}  % uses file education.tex

\makerubric{profex} % needs file profex.tex <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
\makerubric{referee}% uses file referee.tex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Simon <3
your script works like a charm for me! you save my day <3

Comment: doesn't work for me, @Simon can you be more specific please. Do you mean add this line ******  Add from here  <<<<<<<<<<<<< at the start of cv-lit.text and than add this line **********  TO HERE <<<<<<<<<<<< 
That didn't work for me and changing \makerubric{skills} by \makerubric{profex} gave me an error 

My CV template is exactly the same as in the pictures you shared, Thank you in advance

Comment: @Dhouibi iheb Please see the UPDATE i just added with more detailed instructions.